# Google Docs VLOOKUP ISERROR IF function

Tags: excel, vlookup

Below is my excel function input but it does not seem to be working as it just returns -- in google docs.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE)),
    VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE),
    VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!C2:D17, 2, FALSE))
```

Below is the information I am wanting to do a vlookup for.

```
               A    B    C   D

      1       NYJ   27  PHI 20
      2       BUF   13  DET 35
      3       CIN   27  IND 10
      4       MIA   24  NO  21
      5        TB   12  WAS 30
      6       CAR   25  PIT 10
      7       ATL   16  JAC 20
      8        NE   28  NYG 20
      9       MIN   24  TEN 23
      10      STL   24  BAL 21
      11      CHI   16  CLE 18
      12       KC   30  GB  8
      13      DAL   6   HOU 24
      14      DEN   24  ARI 32
      15       SD   6   SF  41
      16      SEA   22  OAK 6
```

Let's say a user inputs "GB" into cell F11. Point of the formula is to insert the points to the right of the GB. Formula is supposed to look for GB in the first column. IF it is TRUE, it will do a vlookup for the first column because it found GB in the first column. IF it is FALSE, it will do a vlookup for the 3rd column.

Not sure what is happening? FYI I did replace the last TWO vlookup functions in the formula with "TRUE" and "FALSE" and it worked as it should. Is this just a google docs issue?

Any help would be great! thanks

*UPDATE*

I tried this in excel and got a #N/A

Answer (score 1):

As you are returning numbers an alternative here might be to use `SUMIF`, i.e.

`=SUMIF(Formulas!A:C,F11,Formulas!B:D)`

If F11 isn't found you'll get zero

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFERROR` instead of `ISERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE),VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!C2:D17, 2, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula will *always* return `#N/A` with your current data. Your `VLOOKUP`s are good, but the issue is with the `IF`. Let me explain:

Let's call `VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE)` the function F1 and `VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!C2:D17, 2, FALSE)` F2.

Your `IF` formula is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(F1),F1,F2)
```

Literally meaning: If F1 returns an error, use F1! If F1 does not return an error, use F2 (which by the way would now return an error).

Does this make sense? Try turning it around:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE)),
VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!C2:D17, 2, FALSE),
VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE))
```

That should work now. You can also shortern it by using an `IFERROR` because you are repeating two operations:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!$A2:$B17, 2, FALSE),VLOOKUP(F11,Formulas!C2:D17, 2, FALSE))
```

Now it means if F1 gives an error, use F2, otherwise, use F1 itself.

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense. just needed to switch them around! THanks and it is working great now! Will make sure to vote you up once i get enough reputation.

Comment: @JohnK You don't need to vote up if you can't, but you can accept an answer by clicking on the tick outline right next to it; and you get a few reputation points in the process :)